# Reflecting letters, to obtain new glyphs

Tags: symbols

How may I reflect a letter, e.g. in the Latin alphabet, to obtain the same difference as we may observe between b and d?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the command `\reflectbox` from the graphics package to define a new command for each mirrored symbol, e.g.:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath, graphicx}
    
    
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\inva}{\text{\reflectbox{a}}} 
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\invb}{\text{\reflectbox{b}}} 
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\invc}{\text{\reflectbox{c}}} 
    
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\invalpha}{\text{\reflectbox{$\alpha$}}} 

    
    \begin{document}
    
    \inva \invb \invc $\invalpha$

    \end{document}
```

[image]